# Access USB camera Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, computer-vision, android-camera2

I'm developing a Xamarin.Android project and I need to get the video flow from the usb camera attached to the android device for the test. Now, I'm using Camera2 API from the Android Open Source project to access each camera frame, but the API with the call to:

```
CameraManager manager =
   (CameraManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);

foreach (string cameraId in manager.GetCameraIdList()){
  
  Console.WriteLine(cameraId); 
}
```

doesn't return the USB camera attached to the device. I've tryed this[1] app to serach the USB camera and the device found it correctly.
Is that I fall to search for available device with the call to `CameraManger.GetCameraIdList()`?

Thanks.
[1]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shenyaocn.android.usbcamera

Comment: I found others use UVCCamera library to access to external camera. The link below maybe helpful. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137785/external-usb-webcam-plugin-for-xamarin-android

Comment: So I've tried to bind the .arr lib to Xamarin.Android poject but this method seem to bee painfull...if I will use Android Studio, there are some way to get access to USB camere attached to the device with Camera2 API? Are this an easiest way in your opinion?Thank's!

Comment: I'm very concerned about this because I've read that not all Android Device support usb external Camera. I'm workin on a Samsung TAB A

Comment: For the specifical device, you need to connect the support from the provider.

Comment: Ok, thank's for the advice!

Comment: @II_gzr Did you find a solution?